# html video doesnt load on mobile. play button strikethrough

Tags: html, css, wordpress, video

GIFs implemented as mobile sometimes don't load on mobile

```
<video src="/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/5.mp4" 
preload="metadata" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" 
muted="muted" controls="controls" width="305" height="170"></video>
```

[This page contains some examples](https://cozylights.de/9-gemuetlichsten-gifs-diesen-herbst/), it includes 10 GIFs and they randomly have errors loading, looking like this:

[image: screenshot from iphone using chrome]

This is all done in wordpress and the GIFs are added to media library.
The error occurs both in safari and chrome, so far I have tried:

```
preload="none", preload="auto", removed preload
```

On desktop browser it works perfectly fine.

Comment: anyone? would really appreciate

Comment: Try loading video file using direct url on phone. It's possible that the video itself is not playable as codecs are not available. P.S. - On chrome ubuntu, this works fine, so a good chance that codec is not supported.

Comment: you are writing about GIFs, but your `video` tags contain mp4 files - confusing?

Answer (score 0):

That might be a matter of the video format not being understood by some OSes. You should also provide the videos in `webm` format as an alternative. (i.e. having two `source` tags inside the `video`tag, with different file formats in the `src` attribute)

Example:

```
<video width="480" height="320" controls>
  <source src="my_movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="my_movie.webm" type="video/webm">
</video>
```

And you could also add an .ogg file

In my experience, "Miro Video Converter" is a good tool to convert video files in a way so that they are recognized by as many browsers/OSes as possible.